# Can't find TF_MIN_GPU_MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I get a message that says my GPU Device is ignored because its multiprocessor count is lower than the minimum set. However, it gives me the environment variable *TF_MIN_GPU_MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT* but it doesn't seem to exist because I keep getting command not found. When I look at the environment variables using *set* or *printenv* and grep for the variable name, it doesn't exist. Does anyone know where I can find it or how I can change its set value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do something like this before running your main script
`export TF_MIN_GPU_MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT=4`

Note though that the default is set for a reason -- if you enable slower GPU by changing that variable, your program may run slower than it would without any GPU available, because TensorFlow will try to put run everything on that GPU

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My goal is to get the fastest possible GPU used and it seems like the one that is being ignored because of its multiprocessor count is faster. Is there a way I can get TensorFlow to use both GPUs? Or what's the most efficient way to utilize my GPUs?

Comment: The most efficient way is to leave things as they are. That GPU is being ignored by default because it's slow (doesn't have enough multiprocessors)

Comment: But in my tensorflow code, can't I designate a job to both GPU's? Isn't it better to have 2 GPUs working on a task than just 1 or is this not how it works? Also, do I have to specifically do something in the code for the GPU to work or will it just automatically use the default GPU instead of the CPU for tasks? Appreciate all the help!

Comment: It'll use the first GPU it finds for everyhing, unless you do `with tf.device("gpu:1")`. Theoretically using two GPUs is faster, but if one GPU is slow, it's easy to shoot yourself in the foot and spend time bottlenecked on that GPU

Comment: Thanks for the response and that makes a lot of sense. Is there a specific rule for what tasks to split among multiple GPUs? Like can I train my model using both GPUs or should I train using one and evaluate with the other so that while the first GPU focuses solely on training the second focuses solely on evaluating (since training usually takes longer than evaluation).

Answer (score 0):

In windows, create a new environmental variable with this name and assign its value.

You can do that by right clicking on the *This PC*  in *File Explorer*, select *Properties* at bottom, then select *Advanced system settings* on left.  That will get you to the System Properties dialog.  Also you can type "environmental properties" in Cortana Search.

From there you click the *Environmental Variables* button.  Once in the *Environmental Variables dialog*, select new to create the variable and assign the value, then back out.  You may have to restart your IDE or open a new DOS window for that environmental variable to be visible.